# How to choose specific minimum values in lists and do mathematical operations on them

Tags: python, python-3.x

After getting data from user input I put the input in lists like this:

- x= [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
- y= [1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 1]

I have manged to write this as:

```
rows = 3
weight = 0
high =0
low =0

while rows>=3 and rows<=200:
    rows, weight = map(int, input().split())
    break
count_input = 0
while count_input<rows:
    while high>=0 and low<=100:
        high, low = map(int, input().split())
        i=i+1
        if count_input==rows:
            break
```

To choose the minimum number in a list i tried this:

```
smallest = None
for number in [1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 2]:
    if smallest is None or number < smallest:
        smallest = number
print('Smallest:', smallest)
```

my questions are:

- How to determine minimum values in these two lists and add minimum values together BUT taking into account that selected minimum values of same positions like x[0] and y[0], or x[1] and y[1] can not be added together.
- Elements in diagonal position to each other like x[0] and y[1], x[2] and y[3] can not be added together
- Also How to put a limit for number of chosen values, like choosing the minimum 4 values found in lists together

Comment: What is the question? -Which part of your specification are you having trouble with?   Welcome to SO please take the time to read [mcve], [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Why declare a `while` ... and then unconditionally break after 1 thing inside it? Remove it!

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yeah because first line is for different inputs, and other while to get other new inputs for different variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would approach finding the minimum of the data set, with the logic for not using values between the lists if they have the same index or a diagonal index

```
x = [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
y = [1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 1]
final_min = max(x) + max(y)


for x_index in range(0, len(x)):
    for y_index in range(0, len(y)):
        if y_index == x_index - 1 or y_index == x_index or y_index == x_index + 1:
            pass
        else:
            test_min = x[x_index] + y[y_index]
            if test_min < final_min:
                print(test_min) # prints 3, 2, 1
                final_min = test_min
print(final_min) # prints 1
```

This makes sense by visually looking at the data, as there are 3 places that the sum would be 1, and the only place it could be smaller (0) would be 0 + 0 but that is a diagonal pair so it cannot be included. You should keep in mind that this is a computationally expensive approach though because it iterates through the `y` list for every index in the `x` list, and if your lists are large this will take a **LONG** time! Also, if the lists are different lengths then the program will likely hit an `IndexError` and I have not included safeguards for that. I cannot help you on your final point because I do not understand what is meant by:

> How to put a limit for number of chosen values, like choosing the minimum 4 values found in lists together

You would need to clarify for anybody to understand what is meant here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! Now i understand your method!

What I meant for the last question:

for example x=[6,5,1,1,1]  and y= [0, 2 ,0 ,3,0] we can choose three 1's from first list and three 0's from second list, but if we want to set that we want only not to choose those minimum 6 values but just choose minimum two value

Comment: @alfredjacob I still do not understand. For each of the combinations the minimum is 1 + 0. This will always equate to 1. Are you asking to count the number of occurrences where 1 + 0 occurs?

Comment: No i mean if you can choose 6 minimum values from two lists, just choose 3 and add them together and don't consider the other 3

Comment: You would just adjust what index you are considering, like `for x_index in range(3, len(x)):` would omit the beginning of the x-list. You could also specify individual numbers such as `for x_index in [0, 3, 4]:` which would only consider 3, 0, and 1 from the x-list. The rest of the code remains unchanged

Comment: @alfredjacob If this solved your problem, I would appreciate it if you accept it as the answer you were looking for by clicking the check mark by my post :)

Answer (score -2):

Use `min(..)` and `index(..)`.

This solution may not be entirely correct, but you get the idea...

```
def add_min_with_constraints(a, b):
  if len(a) == 0 or len(b) == 0:
    return -math.inf
  min_a_i = a.index(min(a))
  min_b_i = b.index(min(b))
  if min_a_i == min_b_i or abs(min_a_i - min_b_i) == 1: # same or diagonal indices
    # exclude the current minimums
    return add_min_with_constraints(a[:min_a_i] + a[min_a_i+1:], 
                                    b[:min_b_i] + b[min_b_i+1:])
```